# Order of files to be executed in linux and how to change it

Tags: linux, execution

What is the order in which executables are searched by linux for executing when a command is executed. I have following:

1. /bin/play
2. /home/prabhat/playframework/play

both the above files are in path.

When I execute it from my home directory as in below

```
prabhat@localhost~/home/prabhat/$ play
```

/bin/play gets executed.

What is the order in which linux searches for files to be executed. Is there a way to change it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The order is defined by the entry order in your [PATH](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html) variable.

Note that your shell may cache this info and when you change the PATH you may need to refresh this cache. In `bash` this is done by the `hash` command. See [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/bash-shell-builtin-commands/) for more information.

> hash command maintains a hash table, which has the used command’s path
>   names. When you execute a command, it searches for a command in the
>   variable $PATH. But if the command is available in the hash table, it
>   picks up from there and executes it

Answer (score 1):

you need to move /home/prabhat/playframework/ before /bin in your path.  you should be able to do this in your .bashrc or .bash_profile

something along the lines of:

```
export PATH=/home/prabhat/playframework/play:$PATH
```

hope this helps

Comment: Implementation of what Brian suggested. It just works...